# query documents that depend on values of other documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Imagine following mongoose model:

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
  //_id: ObjectId,
  //more fields,
  blockedIds: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
})
```

What is the most efficient way to get all users that don't match the blockedIds of an user with a certain _id?

A naive way would be to to perform two queries:

```
User.findById(id).then(user => {
  return User.find({_id: {$nin: user.blockedIds}})
})
```

Is it possible to use the aggregation framework and $facets to accomplish that in one query?

Comment: This should be trivial.You can try `User.find({$expr:{{ $not: [ { $in: [ "$_id", "$blockedIds] } ] }}})` in 3.6. `$expr` is new addtion in 3.6 which allows you to use aggregation comparison operators in regular query. Not sure why `$facets` is needed although

Comment: I think your query returns sth. different than mine.
Woudn't that find all not blocked users of all users?
My query finds all not blocked users of a specific user with a given _id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [non-correlated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#uncorrelated-subquery) sub query from 3.6 for your use case.

Something like

```
User.aggregate(
 [{$lookup:{
   from: "users",
   pipeline:[
    {$match: {_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}},
    {$project: {_id:0,blockedIds:1}}
   ],
   as: "noncr"
 }},
 {$match:{
   $expr:{
     $not:[
      {$in:[
        $_id,
        {$arrayElemAt:["$noncr.blockedIds",0]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
}},
{$project:{noncr:0}}]
)
```

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to pull in the "blockedIds" for input id followed by [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to filter the documents where "_id" is not in list of blockedIds.

[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) allows use of aggregation comparison operators in $match stage.

[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to fetch the first element from $lookup array.

[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) to compare the _id against blockedIds.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) with exclusion to remove the "noncr" field from the final response.

Please note when you test query  use the collection name not model or schema name in "from" attribute of look up stage.

Comment: Great answer! Do you have a solution for mongo 3.4 also?

Comment: Use `$facet` as you've noted. May not be efficient but one can try `User.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "blockedUser": [
       {$match: {_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}},
       {$project: {_id:0,blockedIds:1}}
      ],
      "allUsers": [
        { $match: { } }
      ]
    }
  },
 {$unwind:"$allUsers"},
 {
   "$redact": {
     "$cond": [
       {
        $not:[
          {$in:[
            $allUsers._id,
            {$arrayElemAt:["$blockedUser.blockedIds",0]}
          ]}
        ]
       },
       "$$KEEP",
       "$$PRUNE"
     ]
   }
 }
])`

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework in the other answer is useful, but for the sake of completeness, here's an alternate approach. In Redis db designs, you always have to think of accessing the data from "both ways", so you think of inverting results. So that's what we can do here.

Instead of having `blockedIds` array on user, have a `blockedBy`:

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
  blockedBy: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    index: true,
  }]
});
```

So now you invert the problem and the query becomes trivial:

```
User.find({ userID: { $nin: blockedBy: } });
```

In some situations it could be a viable option.