# Performing nested $in query using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to generate a MongoDB version 3.6 query for the pseudo SQL statement:

```
SELECT table1.c1, table1.c2 
FROM table1 
WHERE (table1.c1 IN (SELECT table2.c1 FROM table2 U0 WHERE (U0.c2 IN (1, 2))))
```

How do i do it? I am looking for a single aggregation query syntax.

**EDIT**

The question is **NOT** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886602/query-documents-that-depend-on-values-of-other-documents-in-mongodb) question. The explanation give there assumed the output array of the lookup stage will be of the form:

```
noncr = [{_id: ObjectID('xxxx'), blockedIDs: [ObjectID('yyy'), ObjectID('zzz')]}]
```

The sql query I am looking at will have the output array of the `$lookup` like this:

```
table2 = [{_id: ObjectID('xxxx'), c1: 35}, 
          {_id: ObjectID('yyyy'), c1: 34}, 
          {_id: ObjectID('zzzz'), c1: 37}]
```

Finally the array needs to be transformed to just

```
table2 = [35, 34, 37]
```

So it can be use like so:

```
$match: {$expr: {$in: [$c1, $table2]}}
```

Essentially, I am looking for a way to transform `table2` as shown above. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query documents that depend on values of other documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886602/query-documents-that-depend-on-values-of-other-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The pipeline is as follows:

```
[{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'table2',
        'pipeline': [{
            '$match': {
                'c2': {
                    '$in': [1,
                    2]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                'col1': True
            }
        }],
        'as': '_nested_in'
    }
},
{
    '$addFields': {
        '_nested_in': {
            '$map': {
                'input': '$_nested_in',
                'as': 'lookup_result',
                'in': '$$lookup_result.c1'
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$in': ['$col1',
            '$_nested_in']
        }
    }
}

]
```

Just discovered the `$map` operator.

Comment: $map not required here. You can replace `{
    '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$in': ['$col1',
            '$_nested_in.c1']
        }
    }
}` Also, arguments to $in are incorrect. The first argument should be value not array. I have added an answer.